# No resource found that mach the given name Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar on Visual Studio - Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to add the AppCompat theme to my android xamarin project but VS is not recognizing the theme. I added the references as you can see in the image.

My styles.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
  </style>
</resources>
```

And I get this error:

```
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'
```

Any help?

[image: Error]
[image: References]

Comment: try removing the reference and delete from the folder add in fresh and the problem was solved for me.

Answer (score 7):

remove the **Xamarin.Android.Support.v4** and **Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat**  from references

Navigate to the C:\Users\your-user\AppData\Local\Xamarin, remove the folders **Xamarin.Android.Support.v4** and **Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat** and also remove the zips in this folder.

Now clean the project and add new references and rebuild again and wait until rebuild finished, **don't stop or cancel the rebuild** otherwise  error occurs

Comment: this is the only solution that works in my case. the first build will cost long time depending on the internet connection, VS will look hung, just wait and don't cancel the build.